# how to programmatically drive VScode with Python, i.e., fully remote control of VSCode?

Tags: remote-control, vscode-api

Is there a way to programmatically drive VScode with Python?  Does VSCode have a regular API that can be used to do full remote control of VSCode?

VSCode does many things well, but many things just take too many steps.  I'd like to use VSCode as an "integrated control center" and server for all the plugins that are available for it, like a multi-database integration engine or Swiss army knife with a single handle.

WHAT I TRIED:
My research found PyWinAuto and other Windows macro-builder-like tools to control VSCode by simulating mouse and keyboard events.  That approach is archaic, low-level and will be extremely tedious to implement.

I hunted on the github.com/vscode and don't see any Python remote control APIs for VSCode. I see many low-level Typescript modules, but these would involve intercepting or wrapping a lot of code.

What is required to do remote control for VSCode? Are there any supported Python packages that already do what I am asking?  Which of the packages in VSCode source code would be the right place to start learning how to do this?